# Both -fPIC and -s used - possibly contradictory?

Tags: gcc, aslr, fpic

In a particular project, I saw the following compiler options used all at once:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo.o -Icomponent1/subcomponent1 -Icomponent2/subcomponent1 -Wall -fPIC -s
```

Are the `-fPIC` and `-s` used together contradictory here? If not, why?

Comment: What does `-s` do? It appears to be undocumented.

Comment: @ams, why, it is in the gcc man page. `-s` strips relocation sections off binaries.

Comment: It's not on my GCC man page. I do see that on the linker man page, and it probably does get passed through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-s` and `-fPIC` are two flags used for different purposes. They are not contradictory.

From the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html)

> -s
>       Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable.
>
> -fPIC
>   If supported for the target machine, emit position-independent code, suitable for dynamic linking and avoiding any limit on the size of the global offset table. This option makes a difference on the m68k, PowerPC and SPARC.